# Search columns for similar formatted data

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How would create a script to search all tables in a database to find columns that have similar formatted data and show which tables have columns with similar formatted data?

```
Pseudo code like this;

 Requester to insert a column
   script searches all tables and columns to find similar formatted data
 Results shows like this
```

Column name | Table name |

If an example code is given with made up data, I should be able to figure it out. Thanks ahead of time!!!!

Comment: Actually not similar columns but similar data in the columns. I'm needing this to quickly know what columns to use to join two tables

Comment: Formatted how - are you only looking at string values? How will you avoid false matches - 'similar' is very vague. Or do you mean columns with the same data type (in `all_tab_columns`) - which would also produce a lot of incorrect potential joins. This is where a relational model of the schema would come in handy.

Comment: Not the same data type. I guess the easiest way to do it is maybe find 5 exact matches of data then I think I can safely assume the two tables can be joined by these two columns. I mean I would still do further research. Kinda looking for a starting point I guess.

Comment: Maybe like if one table has columns NAME,DATE, CITY STATE and another table has NAME,DATE,CITY, STATE and both tables have a STATE column(two letter abbreviation) , I can join hem two by using the STATE column